# OneSignal push notification - Location permission exists but GoogleApiClient timedout

Tags: android, onesignal

I use `OneSignal` for **Push Notifications** in my android app.

But i can not understand that while log level defined as `WARN`.

i see a message like

> "Location permission exists but GoogleApiClient timedout. Maybe
>   related to mismatch google-play aar versions."

I tried but can not fixed it. So i did not send any location data. How it was fired?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This warning is from the OneSignal SDK trying to connect to Google Play services to get the device's location but it timed out due to mixed versions of Google Play services included in the app or when the device is offline in some cases. <strike>This is for an upcoming geotagging feature that will be available on the OneSignal dashboard.</strike> Location radius filtering is available as a segment option on the OneSignal dashboard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think they send location data to cloud. But now not used.

Also sometimes it gets some error.

I think we have to ask OneSignal team :)

Answer (score -1):

You can stop the alert changing the following code from your application class:

```
OneSignal.Current.SetLogLevel(LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, LOG_LEVEL.WARN);
```

to

```
OneSignal.Current.SetLogLevel(LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, LOG_LEVEL.NONE);
```

Comment: The question aims for directions on how to resolve the issue, not how to disable it. (in addition in your proposal disabling all warnings not just this one)